# SQL Server - Pivot without aggregation

Tags: sql-server

I have the following two tables

dimDate dd

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dimDate       dimYear   dimMonth     dimQuarter   dimWeekDayNumber   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-12-01    2019      12           4            5                  |
| .             .         .            .            .                  |
| .             .         .            .            .                  |
| .             .         .            .            .                  |
| 2021-12-10    2021      12           4            5                  |
| 2021-12-11    2021      12           4            6                  |
| 2021-12-12    2021      12           4            7                  |
| 2021-12-13    2021      12           4            1                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Goal Table pg

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| location  goal    startdate   enddate     ptype |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| A         600000  2019-01-01  2019-12-31  CONN  |
| B         400000  2019-01-01  2020-10-01  CONN  |
| C         600000  2019-01-01  NULL        CONN  |
| D         450000  2019-01-01  NULL        CONN  |
| A         500000  2020-01-01  NULL        CONN  |
| B         500000  2020-10-02  2021-03-15  CONN  |
| B         600000  2021-03-16  NULL        CONN  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dimDate           dimYear     dimMonth    dimQuarter  dimWeekDayNumber  A         B       C       D       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-12-01        2019        12          4           7                 600000    400000  600000  450000  |
| .                 .           .           .           .                 .         .       .       .       |
| .                 .           .           .           .                 .         .       .       .       |
| .                 .           .           .           .                 .         .       .       .       |
| 2021-12-10        2021        12          4           5                 500000    600000  600000  450000  |
| 2021-12-11        2021        12          4           6                 500000    600000  600000  450000  |
| 2021-12-12        2021        12          4           7                 500000    600000  600000  450000  |
| 2021-12-13        2021        12          4           1                 500000    600000  600000  450000  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've been trying the SQL pivot operator, but it wants to aggregate, and I've tried using cases but it pulls back four of the same date since I have four locations, with only one location with the goal per row. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can try and use Pivot with MIN/MAX instead of SUM/AVG  as a starting point

Comment: Pivoting *is* a type of aggregation. You cannot pivot without aggregating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I've come up with so far. I don't like it because it isn't dynamic.  I must type in each location explicitly.  Suggestions always welcome.

```
SELECT dd.*, 
    (SELECT goal from mdp.ProductionGoals where dd.dimDate between startdate and isnull(enddate, getdate()) and [location] = 'A') AS  'A' ,
    (SELECT goal from mdp.ProductionGoals where dd.dimDate between startdate and isnull(enddate, getdate()) and [location] = 'B') AS  'B' ,
    (SELECT goal from mdp.ProductionGoals where dd.dimDate between startdate and isnull(enddate, getdate()) and [location] = 'C') AS  'C' ,
    (SELECT goal from mdp.ProductionGoals where dd.dimDate between startdate and isnull(enddate, getdate()) and [location] = 'D') AS  'D' 
FROM mdp.dimDate dd
left outer join mdp.ProductionGoals pg
    on dd.dimdate between startdate and isnull(enddate, getdate())
where dd.dimDate between '2019-01-01' and getdate()
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|dimDate     dimYear  dimMonth  dimQuarter  dimWeekDayNumber   A        B       C       D        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2019-12-01  2019     12        4           7                  600000   400000  600000  450000   |
|.           .        .         .           .                  .        .       .       .        |
|.           .        .         .           .                  .        .       .       .        |
|.           .        .         .           .                  .        .       .       .        |
|2021-12-10  2021     12         4          5                  500000   600000  600000  450000   |
|2021-12-11  2021     12         4          6                  500000   600000  600000  450000   |
|2021-12-12  2021     12         4          7                  500000   600000  600000  450000   |
|2021-12-13  2021     12         4          1                  500000   600000  600000  450000   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need subqueries, you can do this with conditional aggregation. `PIVOT` is a type of conditional aggregation, but you can also use `SUM` or `MAX` with a `CASE` expression, which is far more flexible

```sql
SELECT
    dd.dimDate,
    dd.dimYear,
    dd.dimMonth,
    dd.dimQuarter,
    dd.dimWeekDayNumber,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pg.location = 'A' THEN pg.goal END) AS [A],
    SUM(CASE WHEN pg.location = 'B' THEN pg.goal END) AS [B],
    SUM(CASE WHEN pg.location = 'C' THEN pg.goal END) AS [C],
    SUM(CASE WHEN pg.location = 'D' THEN pg.goal END) AS [D] 
FROM mdp.dimDate dd
left outer join mdp.ProductionGoals pg
    on dd.dimdate between pg.startdate and isnull(pg.enddate, getdate())
where dd.dimDate between '20190101' and getdate()
GROUP BY
  dd.dimDate,
  dd.dimYear,
  dd.dimMonth,
  dd.dimQuarter,
  dd.dimWeekDayNumber;
```

If you want a dynamic solution, I would recommend *not* going down the full dynamic SQL route. Instead, you can select the top four results using `ROW_NUMBER`, `DENSE_RANK`, or other windowing function. I don't know what criteria you would use, but for example the top four locations by total `goal`:

```sql
SELECT
    dd.dimDate,
    dd.dimYear,
    dd.dimMonth,
    dd.dimQuarter,
    dd.dimWeekDayNumber,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pg.rn = 1 THEN pg.goal END) AS [1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN pg.rn = 2 THEN pg.goal END) AS [2],
    SUM(CASE WHEN pg.rn = 3 THEN pg.goal END) AS [3],
    SUM(CASE WHEN pg.rn = 4 THEN pg.goal END) AS [4] 
FROM mdp.dimDate dd
left outer join (
    SELECT *,
        rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalGoal)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          SUM(goal) OVER (PARTITION BY pg.location) AS TotalGoal
        FROM mdp.ProductionGoals pg
    ) pg
    WHERE rn <= 4
) pg on dd.dimdate between pg.startdate and isnull(pg.enddate, getdate())
where dd.dimDate between '20190101' and getdate()
GROUP BY
  dd.dimDate,
  dd.dimYear,
  dd.dimMonth,
  dd.dimQuarter,
  dd.dimWeekDayNumber;
```